# How to attach event listener once properly on ngAfterViewChecked cycle?

Tags: angular, iframe, hook

This is how I did it but I think it should be done better.

Tried ngAfterViewInit either. Not working because then `iframe` is not ready so `load` event never got caught.

```
@ViewChild('ccIFrame') ccIFrame: ElementRef<HTMLIFrameElement>;
attachIFrameListener = false;

ngAfterViewChecked() {
    if (this.ccIFrame && this.attachIFrameListener === false) {
        this.attachIFrameListener = true;
        fromEvent(this.ccIFrame.nativeElement, 'load').subscribe( _ => {
            console.log('attach...event...listener...');
            this.iframeLoaded = true;
            this.toggleFullScreen();
        })
    }
}
```

If I don't have `attachIFrameListener` flag, I will get a lot of `attach...event...listener...`. Which is what ngAfterViewCheck does. No complain.

But the way I avoid that feels just quite `not angular`.

Comment: `ngAfterViewChecked ` is called after the `ngAfterViewInit()` and every subsequent` ngAfterContentChecked()`. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: you can also use `(load)="yourFunction()"` in the .html